# how to make textView expandable by clicking on a button

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitextview

I have many `textViews` on top of a `scrollView` and every `textView` has a custom button over it so that when user click that `textView` it should expand and when it click back then it should collapse to previous position.

what I'm thinking of doing is hide the `smallTextView` and show the `expandedTextView` when button is pressed and when the button is pressed i want to hide `expandedtextView` n show the `smallTextView`. but I don't know how i should do it. any help will be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    self.title = @"Demo";
    appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    for (int i=0;i<[appDelegate.serverResponseArray count];i++)
    {
    self.expandTextView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
    [self.expandTextView setFrame:CGRectMake(8.0f, i*50.0f+10.0f, 270.0f, 40.0f)];
    [self.expandTextView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    [self.expandTextView setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"helvetica" size:12]];
    [self.expandTextView setText:@"Welcome!!!"];
    [self.expandTextView setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:255.0f/255.0f green:255.0f/255.0f blue:255.0f/255.0f alpha:1]];
    [self.expandTextView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.expandTextView];
    self.expandTextView = nil;

    self.expandButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8.0f, i*50.0f+1.0f, 270.0f, 60.0f)];
    [self.expandButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [self.expandButton addTarget:self action:@selector(textButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.expandButton];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(278.0f, i*50.0f+10.0f, 14.0f, 40.0f)];
    [imageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"]];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:imageView];
    imageView = nil;

}


float maxHeight = 0;

    for(UIView *v in [self.scrollView subviews])
    {
        if(v.frame.origin.x + v.frame.size.height > maxHeight)
            maxHeight = v.frame.origin.x + v.frame.size.height;
    }

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(_scrollView.frame.size.width, maxHeight+2570);

}
-(void)textButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Hi");
    [self.expandTextView setHidden:YES\]; 
    NSLog(@"hey");
}
```

[image: in this image every imageView has a custom button over it]
and how do I know which button is getting pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. Your method should look like this :

```
-(IBAction)textButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Hi");
    [self.expandTextView setHidden:YES]; 
    NSLog(@"hey");
}
```

After writing this Method in your `ViewContrller`, wire up your Expand Button's `-touchUpInside` Method to `-textButtonClicked` Method. Use this line :

```
[self.expandButton addTarget:self action:@selector(textButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

instead the one in your code.

Comment: I have provided the code to call your button click method correctly. Now, you have to add some logic.

Comment: ya. I'm not saying anything about logic, i'm saying still the button method is nt getting called.

Comment: @Zac24 : Have you linked that button to this Method ?

Comment: @Zac24 : Use this line : `[self.expandButton addTarget:self action:@selector(textButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];` , instead the one in your code.

Comment: oh. i din see that i was using UIControlEventTouchDragInside. sorry to bother for this small mistake.

Comment: here it is..:P but can u help me with my real problem that how should i make expandable View dynamically.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32005/discussion-between-zac24-and-vin)